# Why is \newcommand ignoring this argument?

Tags: macros

This code runs fine:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\putnode}[1]{\node at (#1,0) (A) {A};}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\putnode(0);
\node at (0,1) (a) {a};
\node at (1,1) (b) {b};
\node at (2,1) (c) {c};
\node at (3,1) (d) {d};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But no matter what argument I give to \putnode, it puts the A at (1,0).  I would think the code above would put A at (0,0) since #1 is replaced by 0.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No, `\putnode(0)` becomes `\node at ((,0) (A) {A};0)`, which is quite wrong. The argument should be surrounded by braces: `\putnode{0}`.

Comment: You can't use `()` delimited arguments with macros defined by `\newcommand`. It is possible when using `xparse` features to define new macros as in your other question, if the argument is defined with `r()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\putnode}[1]{\node at (#1,0) (A) {A};}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\putnode{0}
\node at (0,1) (a) {a};
\node at (1,1) (b) {b};
\node at (2,1) (c) {c};
\node at (3,1) (d) {d};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You had an extra `;` and macro arguments are `{}` delimited not `()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want the format `\putnode(0);` to be used you can use `\def` instead of `\newcommand` and provide a suitable argument text:

```
\def\putnode(#1);{\node at (#1,0) (A) {A};}
```

This defines `\putnode` to expect a `(` after it, then it reads everything to the next `)` as the first argument and finally expects a `;`.

Note that not having the characters exactly like this will trigger an plainTeX error normal LaTeX users might find confusing. It's also not as rebust as the TikZ code and therefore does not allow a space between `)` and `;` for example. However, you could remove the two `;` in the defintion, having `\node` picking up the `;` after the macro usage.